# Usage of EF 4.1 Mapper classes

Tags: entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first

I'm using [EF Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to generate POCO classes from the database that already exists.
It generates a class and a mapper class, for example:
class Person
class PersonMapper
Since I'm using reverse code first, do I really need mapper classes?
I need DB table name and column names and they're generated in Mapper class. 
Should I move them as attributes to POCO class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I'm looking for attributes instead of fluent API is I've already lots of codes and projects working with one class as model to map objects and do validations.

If I want to use fluent API, I've to change lots of code to work with one class and validate with another class.

Hopefully I found a solution by [Rowan Miller](http://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/).

I could move [Table] and [Column] tags to models by using the guide firtst, then did more modifications to move [Required], [RowVersion], [MinLength] and [MaxLength] attributes and get rid of Map class.

Here are the modifications I did in a case if anyone wants to use only attributes instead of fluent API:
[download](http://abugslife.ir/Media/Default/files/ReverseEngineerCodeFirst.zip)

I omitted some attributes and mappings, because I don't need them. And maybe some formatting needed. It is not tested completely!
I'll work more on it and replace the file later.

Answer (score 0):

[EF Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) uses fluent api to map your classes/properties to tables/columns. If all your classes/properties obey EF conventions (You can find out more about conventions by following Ladislav's answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/21c58114-db23-4be5-b810-b078e39d3a2e), then you need neither attributes nor mapper classes. But usually, you have some mappings that do not follow conventions.

Personally, I think using fluent api is a cleaner way since it leaves your poco classes untouched (no attributes needed) and once you get the hang of it, writing in fluent api feels even easier than attributes (At least for me. specially in many-to-many or one-to-many relationships).

And the best of all is EF Power Tools does it all for you. So why bother changing it to attributes or removing them?